# Creating and executing workflow in .net core 3.1

Tags: c#, workflow, .net-core-3.1

I want to create a workflow service in .net core 3.1 where I have to put all the steps in the flow to the database and attach it to the process to track all the steps executing in that flow.
So far I have referred the below link.

[Wokflow demo in mvc](https://medium.com/@alperkarasahin/work-flow-engine-with-c-net-mvc-b8ef2f7ecbdf)